# Edit Manager activePoint "Y" Position ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text

I'm working with TextFlow and EditManager in AS3 (flashx.textLayout)

I want to know how get ActivePosition pointer "Y" position, I know I can get activePosition from EditManager but it's returns character position. I want to count if activePosition out of screen, then scroll down (text is larger and its out of screen). So I need to get PositionY of EditManager.activePosition. I have searched for this, but adobe can't give me complete information.
if you had problem like this please Help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found that.

```
var currPos:int = editManager.activePosition;
var currLineY:int = textFlow.flowComposer.findLineAtPosition(currPos).y;
```

thanks :)